# Can parent and child height both be in percentage?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fill the image exactly to the full screen of the device. So i have given `.container:100%` and body,html to 100% height. Now i want to center align the `child` div vertically no matter what content it has but it should be centered vertically. So i tried giving `50% height` and `25%` on both `margin-top` as well `bottom`. so exactly 100% it should fit as per calc. But it is not happening the way expected.

Why it is not centering vertically? In other words, Why there is no equal space in top and bottom of the div even though i have given equal top and bottom margin with `height:50%;`

How to center align it in vertical? There shouldn't be vertical scroll bar as i have given height as 100% for body,html.container but it is appearing.

**CSS**

```
.child{    
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    margin-top: 25%;
    margin-bottom: 25%;
    background-color: red;
    color:white;
}
html,body,.container{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:url('http://cdn.morguefile.com/imageData/public/files/e/earl53/
                   preview/fldr_2009_05_25/file5821243281047.jpg');
    background-size:cover;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="child">
        Hello i(red color div) should be cenetered in vertical direction
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5LMY7/)

Comment: I have updated om Fiddle check 
http://jsfiddle.net/5LMY7/8/

Answer (score 1):

Margins in percentage are calculated **according to the width of the container**. [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin)

> Percentages refer to the width of the containing block

(refering to margins)

So you can't use margins to verticaly center in CSS (except if you have fixed heights for conatiner and child).

---

**To achive your goal**

You can use **absolute positioning**

CSS for the child to verticaly center:

```
position:absolute;
top:25%;
left:0;
height:50%;
width:100%;
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/chadocat/5LMY7/6/)**

In this fiddle I also made the scrollbars disapear by adding

```
body,html{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: if i add content. the other things are coming top of the div. Messing up

Comment: Do you mean that the height of the div must adapt to it's content?

Comment: I'm trying to use it in bootsrap

Comment: How come it aligned center now? What is the key here?

Comment: Both div should be center aligned side by side

Comment: container should be in left side and other should be in right side

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44775/discussion-between-chadocat-and-sun)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from missing :

```
margin:0;
padding:0;
```

in `html, body, .container`

looks pretty centered to me...http://jsfiddle.net/5LMY7/

**Alternatively....**

If you can fix the `child` height, then you can use `calc`  to help you out :

```
    .child {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px; /* assuming fixed height */
    margin-top: calc(50% - 50px);
    margin-top: -moz-calc(50% - 50px);
    margin-top: -webkit-calc(50% - 50px);
    background-color: red;
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: Try resizing the window/frame to be too small.

Comment: right...this problem is occuring even with `calc`....dont want to use `position`!!

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/38Vb6/)**:

```
body
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;

}

.child{    
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    top: 25%;
    bottom: 25%;
    background-color: red;
    color:white;
    position:absolute;
}
```