# How to center a div in bootsrap vertically which parent is 100% height with body and html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap. I want to have full screen size image of the device size. 
From there two partition one is left side(.container) and other is right side(.other)

How can center the above vertically.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row own-main-container"> 
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
<div class="container">
    <div class="child">Hello</div>
</div>
</div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
<div class="other">
    HIHIHIHIHI
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fUGzV/3/) **NOTE**: resize the window to see both float side by side

already posted a question but it was not clear.

Thanks

Comment: Got no luck in seeing divs floating side-by-side in fiddle.

Comment: Try resize by pulling left bar of output to left site

Comment: I dragged it to full left..!

Comment: Check this link http://i.stack.imgur.com/tjn7D.jpg

Comment: ohh...got it...I got some security problems on my network.!

Comment: Anyways Why dont you try for `margin-top: 30%` for.child &  .other class.

Comment: -1 : Repeating same question rather than participating/responding in the previous one | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994567/can-parent-and-child-height-both-be-in-percentage/20994808#comment31548604_20994808

Comment: I stated this in question itself. quetion was not clear. @NoobEditor

Comment: @sun :  you should have used `edit` option...

Answer (score 0):

Here your two div are centered vertically:
http://jsfiddle.net/9YAWj/

Juste using:

```
.container,.other{
   height:20px;
   margin-top: calc(50% - 20px);
   background-color:white;
}
```